# Import lexisnexis output into R quanteda

Tags: r, tm, quanteda

I would to use Benoit's R-package quanteda to analyze articles exported from lexisnexis. The export is in the standard html-format. I use the tm package + plugin to read the lexisnexis output. Unfortunately, an error occurs when transforming the tm-corpus to quanteda-corpus. Is that function broken, or is there something I get wrong before?

```
library("tm")
library("tm.plugin.lexisnexis")
library("quanteda")

ln <- LexisNexisSource("lexisnexisOutput.html")
cr <- Corpus(ln)
crp <- corpus(cr)

Error in UseMethod("corpus") : 
  no applicable method for 'corpus' applied to an object of class "list"
In addition: Warning message:
In corpus(texts, docvars = metad, source = paste("Converted from tm VCorpus '",  :
  Arguments docvarssource not used.
```

Comment: It's not clear where your "" file is coming from, but replacing with a test file from the package itself (`file <- system.file("texts", "lexisnexis_test_en.html", package = "tm.plugin.lexisnexis"); ln <- LexisNexisSource(file)`) it also seems to throw the same error. Looks like something has gotten out of sync with different versions. Can you clarify which versions of the packages you are running (`sessionInfo()` should tell you)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Packages should be up to date. 
quanteda_0.9.0-1 tm.plugin.lexisnexis_1.2 tm_0.6-2

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by where the file comes from? Its format is the sample as the lexisnexis_test_en.html sample file

Comment: I suggest filing an issue on https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues, and we will get this fixed. Would help if you emailed me the file `lexisnexisOutput.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a limitation of `corpus.VCorpus()` when the texts were a vector of char types, not just a single char type. Fixed in quanteda 0.9.1-6.  See [Issue #80 on GitHub](https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues/80).